# Parallelism debate. Do I need the word "of" to make this correct?

Tags: parallelism

I am having a debate with a friend. 
She thinks this is correct:

> The judge told the jury that he had excused a juror for having
>   purposely provided murder photos to the media and then **of** stashing
>   the money he had received to hide evidence that would support his claim of > innocence.

and I think this is correct:

> The judge told the jury that he had excused a juror for having
>   purposely provided murder photos to the media and then stashing
>   the money he had received to hide evidence that would support his claim of > innocence.

the debate is about whether the **of** is necessary. What do we think?

Answer (score 3):

Parallelism would be "excused a juror **for** having provided photos ... and then **for** stashing ..."

The second **for** is not necessary, but if you are going to include a preposition, **of** is not the right one.

The verb **excused** governs the choice of preposition here.

You are excused for and accused of...